# Importing JSON for use as an array for GoogleMaps Markers

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm still very new to Javascript, and I was looking for some advice.

I have set up the a google maps view to my liking, however it uses an array built into the javascript itself. basically this....

```
  var locations = [
     [9.449062, 7.950439, 0],
     [34.449062, 10.950439, 50]
  ];
```

Where the first two fields are location coordinates, and the third is a value I plan to use at another time.

I've looked at various tutorials, and they ever seem to not work with a local file (i.e. the fileis in the same directory on the filesystem), or the tutorial just does not seem to work.

I know there have been similar questions, however I can't seem to find what works for me.

I was wondering if someone could help me understand how to use a JSON file as an array like above.

Thanks in advance all.

MHibbin

:)

Comment: Does this mean you to load the JSON file with Ajax? You cannot use Ajax when the page is directly loaded form the local file system (there might be some browser settings to allow this though). You'd have to use a web server. If you have Python, just call `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in that directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like perfectly valid JavaScript assignment of object to variable. If you're using them from HTML page, just include script with your data first and then processing script later:

```
<script src="locations.js"></script>
<script src="worker.js"></script>
```

Where locations.js is exactly like quote you've provided and worker.js is something along the lines:

```
for(idx = 0; idx<locations.length; idx++){
  do_something_with(locations[idx])
}
```

Comment: I didn't even think of this (obviously), this should work well actually, because I need to write another script to re-format some data, so I can do it straight into an array now that's in a seperate file.

Thanks very much Oleg.

MHibbin